# Gain shell access to Kubernetes pod

Tags: shell, kubernetes

I was doing some testing/evaluation on a Kubernetes Helm chart created by a 3rd party and wanted to gain shell access to pods. This immediately lead to several questions:

- How do I find ***which services*** are running on ***which pods***?
- How do I gain a shell on the desired pod?

Answer (score 0):

Due to abstraction in ***K8s***, different services can be running on different pods. So before you can connect to anything, you need to gather some further information:

### Step 1: List pods

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

Which in this example shows we have (2) pods running on the same node "***wordpress-w9ga***":

```
NAME                 READY  STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE          
my-release-mariadb   1/1    Running      0      2d2h   10.10.10.1   wordpress-w9ga
my-release-wordpress 1/1    Running      3      2d2h   10.10.10.2   wordpress-w9ga
```

### Step 2: Use `kubectl` to gain shell on desired pod

The pod I want to get a shell on is "***my-release-wordpress***". **HOWEVER**: Although we see IP's in the output of `kubectl get pods`, ***SSH*** will **NOT** be running. So we're going to gain a shell with the `kubectl` command, specifying the name of the pod we want to access:

```
kubectl exec -it my-release-wordpress -- /bin/bash
```

Comment: Why not “restart” the pod using Kubernetes tools?

Comment: Wouldn't that potentially restart other services?

Comment: Assuming you’re still talking about services in the traditional sense (rather than [the Kubernetes sense](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)), yes, other services running in the pod would be stopped and started, but pods should only run single services or very tightly-coupled services anyway (which you would want to restart together). Going into running pods and changing things there directly is a big step on the road to a messed up Kubernetes setup.

Comment: It was exactly for the reason you noted (that a pod can contain other services). I wanted to ensure I was working in isolation with a single service.  BTW, I was just validating my understanding about how the gears were turning rather than doing any material changes. And also wanted the shell for purposes of snooping around inside the pod ;-)

Comment: Right, I understand the appeal of poking around pods ;-). (I use [kubebox](https://github.com/astefanutti/kubebox) for that.) Perhaps you could mention the context in your question and answer, because I don’t think your answer is good general-purpose advice.

Comment: Will do bud.  Being old school, I like to be able to get into things.  Will adjust the phrasing-

Comment: For readability, moved further comments to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100036/discussion-between-f1linux-and-stephen-kitt).